# Google not crawl my website

Tags: wordpress, google-crawlers

I am new here please suggest me what the issue if google not crawl [my website](http://www.spisehusetfaaborg.dk/).

As per google webmaster I find issue that there is not `robot.txt` file existing.
So i manually added that file on root but still I can't see google crawl the site.
what the issue here?
Also is this can be issue of html + wp theme (if any file required that missing in theme folder) or any thing else?

Thanks

Comment: How long are you already waiting for google to crawl?

Comment: Its approximate 10 day when i done with this site is there any problem can be in code + wp theme etc

Answer (score 0):

Your robots.txt is incorrect.

http://www.spisehusetfaaborg.dk/robots.txt says

```
User-agent: *
Allow: http://www.spisehusetfaaborg.dk/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
```

Whereas to do what you want, you're probably thinking of this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
```

By default everything is allowed, so you don't have to specify an "Allow:" line. In fact your current file says that it can index only "http://www.spisehusetfaaborg.dk/http://www.spisehusetfaaborg.dk/"

Also keep in mind that Google can take a while to index your site. The last time I tried it, it took about a day.

Comment: This is i just added now but site not crawling since last 10 days

Comment: It looks like Google has now indexed your website after you made the robots.txt change mentioned above.